# How do I create an data entry spreadsheet with validation per row in Excel

Tags: excel, validation

I need to create a spreadsheet to be fed into OLTP that validates the data in each row before allowing the row to be added so there can be no partially completed rows in the table.

The columns are:

Description, SKU, Display SKU, Type, Brand Logo URL, Disabled

Here the validation rules would be pretty simple. All fields except 'Brand Logo URL' are required and Disabled is Yes / No.

**Note: I know how to set up validation rules for specific cells, but not for an indeterminate number of rows.**

As an exmaple:

[image: Example image]

Here line 1 would be fine, but line because cell D3 is blank it would flag as a validation error an not allow the row to be added.

Thanks!